# App install via Android Studio starts at boot but not if installed as an .apk

Tags: android, mobile, logcat, mobile-application

I've got an app with the following in the manifest

```
 <receiver android:name="com.redacted.BroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>



<activity android:name="com.redacted.activity.UserLaunch" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="standard" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If I install and run the app via Android Studio, then reboot the phone then the BroadcastReceiver's `onReceive()` gets called as a consequence of connectivity changes settling down after boot up.

However if I build an .apk and then install that, then on device reboot the `onReceive()` is not getting called. (There is a `Log.d()` statement in the `onReceive` which I'm looking for in `logcat` after bootup, it appears with the first installation method but not with the second).

Why is there this difference?

Comment: When you run from Android Studio, does an activity appear?

Comment: Yes an activity appears, I updated the question with more of the manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps are installed in a so-called "stopped state". It takes an explicit `Intent` starting up one of the app's components to move out of the stopped state. Usually, that's running the launcher activity. While in the stopped state, no registered broadcast receivers will work.

So, when you run from Android Studio, the launcher activity moves your app out of the stopped state, and all is good. Installation by some other means would require you to run the launcher activity yourself to move out of the stopped state.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not fully clear.  If I install via Android Studio, then reboot the device. Isn't the act of rebooting going to halt anything that Android Studio and the launcher activity did? Especially if I kill the app first before rebooting?

Comment: Further I was under the impression an intent would come from the OS to the broadcast receiver after reboot (or rather as a consequence of connectivity changes occuring after the reboot), it that incorrect?

Comment: Sorry one more question, is the situation changed if its a system app in rom?

Comment: @Piepants: "Isn't the act of rebooting going to halt anything that Android Studio and the launcher activity did?" -- being in or out of the stopped state is persistent and survives a reboot. "an intent would come from the OS to the broadcast receiver after reboot" -- no, an `Intent` will be broadcast. However, your receiver does not exist, in effect, until you are moved out of the stopped state. A radio might be tuned to a radio station, and that station might be broadcasting, but if the radio is not turned on, you still won't hear anything. :-)

Comment: @Piepants: "is the situation changed if its a system app in rom?" -- I presume that there is a way to have pre-installed apps automatically be out of the stopped state, but I do not know the exact procedure for how to set that up.

Comment: FYI I installed the apk into /system/app and after  rebooting the Broadcast receiver was called.